# Implementation of read-only singleton in Python Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, singleton

### Situation

When the Django website starts up, it need to load some data from a table in the database for computation. The data is read-only and large (e.g. 20MB).

The computation will be invoked every time a certain page is open. A module will use the data for computation. Therefore, I don't want the module to SELECT and load data every time the page is open.

### Question

I guess singleton may be one of the solutions. How to implement the singleton in Django? Or is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Use of Django caching will be best here. You will need to use a 3rd party caching server e.g. `Redis`.  There is `Memcached` too, but as you said your data is 20MB so you will need `Redis` as `Memcached` only allows `1MB` at max per key.

Also using cache is very easy, you just need to `sudo apt-get install redis`, add `CACHES` setting in Django settings and you will be good to go.

Redis (or Memcached) are in-memory cache servers and hold all the cached data in memory, so getting it from Redis will be as fast as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

If when you say "data is read-only" you mean never changes, pre-calcule your data and store it in DB instead of store the large database.

If not, you can use a caching system using `Memcache` or `Redis` or so.

The idea:

- Try to get the data you need.
- If doesn't exist calculate it and store it in cache.

If you are deploying using `GAE` `Memcache` is the easiest on my experience. If not, I use to use `Redis`. Anyway, Django provides [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a singleton class:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Then extend it in your class that contains the functions returning your selection:

```
class SampleClass(Singleton):
    data = None

    def load_data(self):
        self.data = MyModel.objects.all()

    def get_data(self):
        if self.data is None:
            self.load_data()
        return self.data
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is caching I think. Did you check [django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/)? [Database caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#database-caching) seems the relevant part for you.

It basically enables you to store results of database queries for using later without querying again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to create singleton class/object in Python:

First, you should define a base class as following:

```
class Singleton(object):
    """
    This is a base class for building a singleton class.
    Just inherited this class!
    e.g.
        class MySingleton(Singleton)
    Note that not implement a __init__ method for these
    classes to avoid some mistakes.
    """

    _singletons = {}
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._singletons.has_key(cls):
            cls._singletons[cls] = object.__new__(cls)
        return cls._singletons[cls]
```

Then just write a derived class extend it.
That's all!